# Hide UserControl from the Toolbox in CF

Tags: c#, .net, user-controls, compact-framework

I have created a UserControl which contains more UserControls called ucItem. How can I hide ucItem from the Designer (the toolbox)?

I have tried to hide it in the XMTA File, but it does not work.

```
<Class Name="MyFramework.ucItem">
   <DesignTimeVisible>false</DesignTimeVisible>
</Class>
```

Answer (score 1):

I got this working in VS 20080 using the XMTA file, however:

- I had to follow [these steps](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180789(v=vs.90).aspx) to create the XMTA file, otherwise it would be ignored
- After rebuilding, the toolbox still contained the item; a restart of Visual Studio was also required, then it was gone

You could try following [those steps](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180789(v=vs.90).aspx) to hide a property, so you can at least verify that the XMTA is being processed.